# how do I adjust for weekends?

Tags: php, mysql

I am selecting records from my table that have been posted within the past day. This is for an internal site, where there are no posts on Saturdays or Sundays.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This works fine if today is a weekday or Saturday (where the previous day is Friday). If today is Sunday, I'd like to get records for Friday but currently my code shows records for Saturday (which are obviously blank, given that no one posts on Saturday). How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Before the query is made, look what weekday it is (in PHP). Adjust the  interval specified in the query accordingly.

Comment: As @Pekka suggests, if you're using PHP, adjust the query for the date you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [`WEEKDAY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) operator. It returns the index of the day in the week.
0 = Monday and 6 = Sunday

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date = CASE WEEKDAY(CURDATE())                 -- Switch on day index
    WHEN 6 THEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)  -- If sunday, back 2 days
    WHEN 0 THEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)  -- If monday, back 3 days
    ELSE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)         -- Else back 1 day
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PHP:

```
<?php

$c_day = date('w');

if ($c_day == 6) {
    $day_interval = 2;
} else if ($c_day == 0) {
    $day_interval = 3;
} else {
    $day_interval = 1;
}

$query = "
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $day_interval DAY)
";

echo "
c_day = $c_day
$query
";

?>
```

Echoes (on a Saturday):

```
c_day = 6

SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

http://codepad.org/m4TuyGMX

**EDIT**

Note, `sunday` should have been `0`. Here's a test:

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $c_day = date('w', strtotime("last monday +$i day"));

    if ($c_day == 6) {
        $day_interval = 2;
    } else if ($c_day == 0) {
        $day_interval = 3;
    } else {
        $day_interval = 1;
    }

    $query = "
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $day_interval DAY)
";

    echo "
c_day = $c_day (".date('l', strtotime("last monday +$i day")).")
$query
";
}

?>
```

http://codepad.org/StoUfOG2